# BadImageFormatException when attempting to use LuaInterface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, dll, lua

I imported LuaInterface into a console project, referenced it, and wrote a small test script. When i run it, i get this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'LuaInterface, Version=2.0.0.16708, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Forgive me for being a newbie or something, but i can't figure out what it means. What am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you running on a 64-bit operating system?

If you are then you'll need to either get an x64 build of LuaInterface or set the platform target of your console project to x86.

[image: Build properties screenshot]

You can read up on the platform target option here:
http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/

Comment: There does not seem to be a x64 build of LuaInterface anywhere... Do you have a link?